# Fixing chart- label colors in Stacked area chart using VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I am trying to create a dashboard that allows the user to opt for either Line or Stacked area chart. The color codes for each of the label(category) is already pre-decided. The code for chart formatting works fine for the Line chart. However, it doesn't when i opt for Stacked-Area chart visualization. Below is the code for Line chart:

Public Function ChartSeriesFormat()

```
Dim objDictChartColor   As Object       
Dim varChartColor       As Variant      
Dim rngChartColor       As Range        
Dim objSalesChart       As Chart         
Dim rngTemp             As Range        
Dim strSeriesName       As String       
Dim lngStartRow         As Long        
Dim lngColor            As Long         
Dim lngItem             As Long         

' --> Assign objects
Set objSalesChart = shtOutput.ChartObjects("chtMarketShare").Chart
varChartColor = shtMapping.Range("rng_ChartColor").CurrentRegion
Set rngChartColor = shtMapping.Range("rng_ChartColor").CurrentRegion
Set objDictChartColor = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For lngItem = 1 To UBound(varChartColor, 1)
    If Not objDictChartColor.exists(LCase(varChartColor(lngItem, 1))) Then
        objDictChartColor.Add LCase(varChartColor(lngItem, 1)), rngChartColor.Cells(lngItem, 1).Interior.Color
    End If
Next lngItem

lngStartRow = shtOutput.Range("rng_OutputDB1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

For lngItem = 1 To objSalesChart.SeriesCollection.Count
    With objSalesChart
        'Make all the lines in the series xlcontinous
        .SeriesCollection(lngItem).Border.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        strSeriesName = LCase(.SeriesCollection(lngItem).Name)
        lngColor = objDictChartColor.Item(strSeriesName)
        .SeriesCollection(lngItem).Border.Color = lngColor
    End With
Next

On Error Resume Next
    With shtOutput.Range("rng_OutputDB2")
        If .Offset(1).Value <> "" Then
            Set rngTemp = .CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        End If
    End With
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0: On Error GoTo -1
        GoTo ClearMemory
    End If
Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0: On Error GoTo -1


For lngItem = lngStartRow To objSalesChart.SeriesCollection.Count
    With objSalesChart
        'Make all the lines in the series xlcontinous
        .SeriesCollection(lngItem).Border.Color = objSalesChart.SeriesCollection(lngItem - (lngStartRow - 1)).Border.Color
        .SeriesCollection(lngItem).Border.LineStyle = xlDot
    End With
Next
```

ClearMemory:

End Function

The option to choose "Stacked-Area" chart was added later. Any help?

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: @FunThomas The color of the categories(area fill color) change as soon as one clicks on the "Area stacked chart" radio button, even though the Line color follows the stored/intended format.